# How to use change stress in words. Azure Speech

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

Please tell me how I can change the stress in some words in the Azure voice engine text-to-speech. I use Russian voices. I am not working through SSML.
When I send a text for processing, then in some words he puts the stress on the wrong syllable or letter.
I know that some voice engines use special characters like + or 'in front of a stressed vowel. I have not found such an option here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the stress for individual words you can use the SpeakSsmlAsync method and pass a lexicon url or you can directly specify it directly in the ssml by using the phoneme-element. In both cases you can use IPA.